# Angularjs directive for replacing text

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new at angularjs and I want to create a directive to change text for human readable.

scope including records coming from database. I want to change them matching **humanReadable** array.

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .directive("humanReadable", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            replace: true
        }
    });

   var humanReadable= [{
        text: "first_name",
        replace: "First Name"
    }, 
    {
        text: "last_name",
        replace: "Last Name"
    }];

function MyCtrl($scope) {   
    $scope.comesFromDatabase = ["first_name", "last_name"];
}
```

my html is like this.

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in comesFromDatabase">{{item}} - 
                <span human-readable="item"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and [jsfiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/vhbg6104/1/)

Answer (score 3):

As Martinspire mentioned, it's better to use a filter which might look something like below -

```
angular.module('myapp')
    .filter('humanReadable', [function () {
        return function (str) {
            return str.split("_").join(" ").replace(/([^ ])([^ ]*)/gi,function(v,v1,v2){ return v1.toUpperCase()+v2; });

        };
    }]);
```

If you want directive only, with a bit of modification for the above code, it looks like this -

```
 angular.module('myapp')
        .directive('humanReadable', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    element.html(attrs.humanReadable.split("_").join(" ").replace(/([^ ])([^ ]*)/gi,function(v,v1,v2){ return v1.toUpperCase()+v2; }));
                }
            };
        });
```

Edit: I have done it without using your humamReadable array to generalize it assuming that you might find it useful instead of using a separate array.

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .directive("humanReadable", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            items: '=',
            humanReadable: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.items.forEach(function (item, i) {
                if (item.text === scope.humanReadable) {
                    element.text(item.replace);
                }
            });

        }
    }
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vhbg6104/4/**

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to use a custom filter. You can read all about it in the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter or api https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter
You could take some inspiration from the translate-filters too: https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate
In summary, you would probably write it like so: `{{item | human-readable}}` or with `ng-bind` like so: `<span ng-bind="item | human-readable">`

Use the tools and i'm sure you can figure something out